# How to send multiple data into view with their required relationships

Tags: php, html, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am working on a Laravel 5.8 project which is an Online Store. and in this project, I wanted to add "Printing Order Factors" feature for Admins.

So I have made a form like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('orders.newprint') }}">
    @csrf
    @forelse($orders as $order)
    <tr>
        <td><input class="form-check-input" name="orderCheck[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $order->ord_id }}">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>{{ $order->ord_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->status_label }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->customer_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->ord_total }}</td>
    </tr>
    @empty
        <td colspan="7" class="text-center">No order to show</td>
    @endforelse
</form>
```

So basically admins can select multiple orders like this:

[image]

And I'm trying to send order ids as an array:

`<input class="form-check-input" name="orderCheck[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $order->ord_id }}">`

So after clicking *Print All Order Factors*, it should be showing **all the order factors at one page**.

So in order to do that, I have added this method at the Controller:

```
public function prnpriview(Request $request)
    {
        $orders = $request->input('orderCheck');
        foreach($orders as $ord){
            $order = Order::find($ord);
            $args = [
                'order'  => $order,
                'address'  => $order->order_address->first(),
                'details'  => $order->orderDetail,
                'sendType'  => $order->productSubmit,
                'coupons'  => $this->cartController->computeDiscountForOutRequests($order->ord_object_id, $order->ord_creator_id),
                'user'      => User::query()->find($order->ord_creator_id)
            ];

        }
        return view('admin.shop.orders.newprint', $args);
    }
```

However the problem with this is that, it only sends the last `order` and not all of them.

The controller code used to work fine for one order. But I need to pass multiple orders to `newprint.blade.php`.

So the question is, how to send all of the orders that have been checked by user and send them to view with their `args` array (required relationships)?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys about this...

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE #1**

Here is my code at `newprint.blade.php` which shows every order factor details for printing:

```
@foreach($args as $arg)
    <p>Order Id:
        <strong>
            {{ digits2persian($order->ord_id) }}
        </strong>
    </p>
    <p>Address:
        <strong>
            {{ $address->province_relation->prv_name }}،
            {{ $address->city_relation->cit_name }}،
            {{ $address->address }}
        </strong>
    </p>
    ...
@endforeach
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

If I `dd($args)` before `return` in the Controller, and if I `{{ dd($args) }}` in the view, I get this as result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close :) You need to create an array of arrays using `$arg`. Right now, in the loop, it's replacing the value of the array each time it loops through it.

```
$args = [];
foreach($orders as $ord){
    $args[] = [
        ...
    ];
}
```

Comment: Then at the `newprint` blade, I said `@foreach($args as $arg) ... @endforeach` but this will return `Undefined variable: args`

Comment: @KKKKKK try it with this syntax `return view('admin.shop.orders.newprint', ['args' => $args]);`

Comment: I just added my code at the view `newprint.blade.php`

Comment: @KKKKKK if you `dd($args)` before the return and in the view and before the foreach in the blade, what do you get? You need to do a bit of debugging there

Comment: Try to add compact in the view to send the variable with the info to the blade page `return view('admin.shop.orders.newprint', compact('args'))` @KKKKKK

Comment: It properly shows the selected orders. I just added an **UPDATE #2** about this...

Comment: Now I get `Undefined variable: order` in the view blade!

Comment: @KKKKKK it's normal, no need to be chocked. The `$args` variable exists, but in the blade file you're using `$order->ord_id` and `$address->...` and these two variables do not exist. If you want to use a variable, you need to pass it to the view. Maybe you're looking for `$arg->ord_id`? ;) Re-read your logic carefully.

Comment: No the `$args` is array itself that contains `order`, `address`, `details`, `sendType`, `coupons` and `user` information of an Order. The controller code used to work fine for one order. But I need to pass multiple orders to `newprint.blade.php`

Comment: You do NOT need to pass multiple orders to the view, everything is in the `$args` variable.  Inside the foreach you should use `$arg->order->ord_id` and `$arg->address->province_relation->prv_name` ... etc. It's hard debugging code I do not see in detail, but that's the general idea.

Comment: Now you enter to the array in the right way `$arg->order->property` @KKKKKK

Comment: @KKKKKK just a suggestion, instead of making 2 DB calls for each order you can simply make 1 DB call for all the orders id's you're receiving from the input and moving `Orders` query out of `foreach` loop and using relationship with `User` model. Something like this `$orders = Order::with('user)->whereIn('order_id', $orderIds)->get();` and then you can iterate over this collection to avoid multiple database calls/operations